# jsoup select exclude

Tags: html, jsoup

```
<li><div class="a">xxx<div></li>
<li><div class="b">xxx<div></li>
<li><div class="b">xxx<div></li>
```

How to select `li` elements that do not contain

```
<div class="a">
```

The expected result would be:

```
<li><div class="b">xxx<div></li>
<li><div class="b">xxx<div></li>
```

```
select("li").not(has("div.a"))
```

?

Comment: I don't know much about jsoup, but this is the jQuery selector: `li:not(:has(.a))`. jsoup seems to support all of those pseudo-selectors.

Answer (score 0):

add id and value to li and then,

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function check(){
                var li = document.getElementById("li").value;
            if(li == 1){
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML= "result = "+"<div class='b' style='border:1px solid red;'>abc</div>";
            }
              alert(li);

        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="check()">
    <li id="li" value="1">
        <div class='a'>abc</div>
    </li>
    <li id="li" value="2">
        <div class="b">bcd</div>
    </li>

    <span id="result">

    </span>
    </body>
</html>
```